# Doctor's translation in the God Complex refers to whom?

Tags: doctor-who

In The God Complex, the Doctor translates...

> An ancient creature, drenched in the blood of... I'm not talking about me

Who was the creature referring to? The easy answer is the Doctor himself, but I am not completely sold on that. Perhaps it's related to the Doctor's fear or faith? He never answered what was in that room. Maybe...

> The corpses or Amy and Rory?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is referring to the Doctor.

> The Doctor, at first, assumes the Minotaur is describing itself, but only after the last line does the Doctor realize what we've known all along—that the Minotaur is talking about *both* itself and the Doctor.

That is, the reason that moment is important is not because of what the viewer sees, but rather the impact it has on the Doctor himself.

It doesn't refer to:

- the others, because it's using the singular
- Amy or Rory, because while both can be argued to be *ancient* for different reasons, the other grimmer attribute doesn't apply

> Furthermore, the series has had a lot of introspection by the Doctor into who he really is: the heroic physician or the "mighty warrior"—this description tallies with the Doctor perfectly, and further serves to demonstrate to him who he really is. It no doubt influences his decision to leave Amy and Rory.

Comment: Based on the sound from The Doctor's room I got the impression that what was in there was seen in The Doctor's Wife episode. Perhaps I need to re-watch The God Complex.

Comment: @Xantec: That's just the Cloister Bell. It has nothing to do with _The Doctor's Wife_ specifically; rather, it's the TARDIS's alert sound and it thematically signals "serious trouble" for Mr Doctor.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Time of The Doctor, the Doctor's fear is shown to be the crack in time and space.

Comment: Or it could be the TARDIS blowing up...

Comment: No, seriously....it was openly stated in Time of the Doctor that it was the crack.